# Defining a matrix with constant numeric values

Tags: r, matrix

I have updated R to the latest version 3.6.0 and also all the packages. I ran a simple code, though it worked earlier many times but not this time. The code with the issue is as below

```
 ff=matrix(0,5,15)
```

> Error in matrix(0, 5, 15) : unused argument (15)

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: could you please tell me the reason why this does not work for me ? I really don't understand the meaning of "unused arguments ".

Comment: Try to restart R. If you're using RStudio, restart it too.

Comment: I did it , but still did not work . Don't know why.

Comment: Please try restarting R **without loading** any packages and then try again. Could be some package is masking `matrix`. Also, please share `sessioninfo::session_info()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
ff=matrix(data = 0, nrow = 5, ncol = 15)
```

It is always suggested to use argument names. Even if there is any mismatch in argument's position, this should take care of it.

Comment: ff=matrix(data = 0, nrow = 5, ncol = 15)
Error in matrix(data = 0, nrow = 5, ncol = 15) : 
  unused arguments (data = 0, nrow = 5, ncol = 15)
>The issue still persists.